# Why isn't my platform event chain working?

Tags: apex, asynchronous, platform-event, recursion

I've create the following method:

```
//@NotForProduction
public class TEST_SandboxDataFactory {
    public static void create() {
        List<String> sObjectTypeNameList = new List<String>();
        for (SObjectType sObjectType : XFTY_DummySObjectFactoryOutletLookup.OUTLET_TYPE_BY_SOBJECT_TYPE.keySet()){
            sObjectTypeNameList.add(sObjectType.getDescribe().getName());
        }
        System.System.debug('########### sObjectTypeNameList:' + sObjectTypeNameList);
        DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler.publish(sObjectTypeNameList);
    }
}
```

I have the following trigger:

```
trigger DummyDataCreationEventTrigger on DummyDataCreationEvent__e (after insert) {
    System.System.debug('########### DummyDataCreationEventTrigger:' + Trigger.new);
    DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler.Instance.handleTrigger();
}
```

and this trigger handler:

```
public class DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
    XAP_TRIG_TriggerWrapper triggerWrapper;

    private DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler(XAP_TRIG_TriggerWrapper triggerWrapper) {
        this.triggerWrapper = triggerWrapper;
    }

    private DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler() {
        this(new XAP_TRIG_TriggerWrapper());
    }

    public static DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler instance {
        get {
            return new DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler();
        }
        private set;
    }

    private static final String SEPARATOR = '\n';

    public static void publish(List<String> sObjectTypeList) {
        System.System.debug('########### sObjectTypeList:' + sObjectTypeList);
        Database.SaveResult result = EventBus.publish(new DummyDataCreationEvent__e(
                SObject_Types__c = String.join(sObjectTypeList, SEPARATOR)
        ));
        System.System.debug('########### result:' + result);
    }

    protected override void handleAfterInsert() {
        List<DummyDataCreationEvent__e> dummyDataCreationEventList
                = (List<DummyDataCreationEvent__e>) this.triggerWrapper.newSObjectList;
        System.System.debug('########### dummyDataCreationEventList:' + dummyDataCreationEventList);

        List<String> sObjectTypeList = new List<String>();
        for (DummyDataCreationEvent__e dummyDataCreationEvent: dummyDataCreationEventList) {
            String sObjectTypeListString = dummyDataCreationEvent.SObject_Types__c;
            sObjectTypeList.addAll(sObjectTypeListString.split(SEPARATOR));
        }

        Schema.SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectTypeList.remove(0));
        System.System.debug('########### sObjectType:' + sObjectType);

        try {
            new XFTY_DummySObjectSupplier(sObjectType)
                    .setQuantityPerTemplate(10)
                    .setInclusivity(XFTY_InsertInclusivityEnum.ALL)
                    .setInsertMode(XFTY_InsertModeEnum.NOW_BEST_EFFORT)
                    .supplyBundle();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '!!! Failed to create data for ' + sObjectType);
        }

        if (!sObjectTypeList.isEmpty()) {
            publish(sObjectTypeList);
        }
    }
}
```

The trigger framework is known to work as expected, even if there are some silly things about it.

My expectation is that when I anonymously execute

```
TEST_SandboxDataFactory.create();
```

The system will:

1. Publish instance of DummyDataCreationEvent__e.
2. DummyDataCreationEventTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert() will then:
3. Extract sObjectTypeList from the instance of DummyDataCreationEvent__e.
4. Pop the first SObjectType out of List sObjectTypeList
5. Create data for SObjectType
6. If sObjectTypeList has remaining items, publish a new instancew of DummyDataCreationEvent__e
7. Repeat 2 through 5 until the list is exhausted.

In actuality, the trigger never seems to run and my log displays:

> 21:01:11.855 (6811905198)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|###########
>   sObjectTypeNameList:(Account, Account_Channel__c,
>   Acc_Channel_and_Item_Group_Connection__c,
>   Account_and_Item_Group_Connection__c, Adyen_Payment_Line__c,
>   Adyen_Payment_Transaction__c, Agent__c, Apparels_sizes_order__c,
>   APXT_CMQR__Conga_Merge_Query__c, ATP__c, ...) 21:01:12.857
>   (6857679135)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|###########
>   sObjectTypeList:(Account, Account_Channel__c,
>   Acc_Channel_and_Item_Group_Connection__c,
>   Account_and_Item_Group_Connection__c, Adyen_Payment_Line__c,
>   Adyen_Payment_Transaction__c, Agent__c, Apparels_sizes_order__c,
>   APXT_CMQR__Conga_Merge_Query__c, ATP__c, ...) 21:01:12.857
>   (6878399052)|USER_DEBUG|[26]|DEBUG|###########
>   result:Database.SaveResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=3375d195-791e-4e58-b77e-f5c23929c4c6;getStatusCode=OPERATION_ENQUEUED;]);getId=e02xx0000000001AAA;isSuccess=true;]

I find it utterly bizarre that this log contains "isSuccess=true" within a list of Database.Error.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code/transaction run by a Platform Event Trigger is run as the "Automated Process" User, and won't show up in logs unless you specifically set up a debug log for the "Automated Process" traced entity type.

Comment: Can you please include more specific directions how to set up a debug log for the "Automated Process" traced entity type?

Comment: @BrianKessler It's literally just going to the debug logs page in setup, setting up a new user trace flag, and selecting "Automated Process" from a picklist.

Comment: Found it, thanks.  :-)  ... but I don't think the system is actually getting so far as to do anything with the automated processes... no logs.

Comment: Never mind... it seems to be working now.... (all of it.) :-)